# Java Android: Calling a Method

Tags: java, android, networking, methods, call

I'm building a list view android application.
I want a message to be returned when a url is clicked from the list which is in an array telling the user if the site is offline or online. I am doing this by a quick ping which returns a Boolean value to say this. I am a java newbie and I know it is something to do with the way I am calling the pinUrl() method as when I remove said if statement from onListItemClick() the app does no crash.

Here is my MainActivity for reference:

```
package com.seven.webtools;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Resources res = getResources();
    String[] Sites = res.getStringArray(R.array.Sites);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Sites));

}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // Get the selected url
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    String address = o.toString();

    //Ping the address
    String Status = "offline";
    if (MainActivity.pingUrl(address) == true){
        Status = "online";
    }

    //Return the result
    Toast.makeText(this, address + " is " + Status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public static boolean pingUrl(final String address) {
     try {
      final URL url = new URL("http://" + address);
      final HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      urlConn.setConnectTimeout(1000 * 10); // mTimeout is in seconds
      final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      urlConn.connect();
      final long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      if (urlConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
       System.out.println("Time (ms) : " + (endTime - startTime));
       System.out.println("Ping to "+address +" was success");
       return true;
      }
     } catch (final MalformedURLException e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
     } catch (final IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return false;
    }

}
```

Thank you very much if you can help me out :)

Comment: hmmm whats the problem?

Comment: When I click one of the list items I get the "App has stopped working" message.

Comment: Please post the stack trace from logcat.  It will show exactly what and where the problem is.

Comment: I have the LogCat window open, what do you need to know?

Answer (score 1):

You should use either an `AsyncTask` or a `Thread` and `Handler`.

Here's an example of a `Thread` and `Handler`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Resources res = getResources();
        String[] Sites = res.getStringArray(R.array.Sites);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Sites));
    }

    // Here is where we create our Handler that will receive the Message from the thread.
    private Handler handler = new Handler()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            str.append((String) msg.obj).append("\r\n");
            str.append("response:  " + msg.arg1).append("\r\n");
            str.append("time: " + msg.arg2).append("\r\n");

            System.out.println(str.toString());
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        final String address = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

        // We create a new thread and implements the Runnable interface
        new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                URL url;
                HttpURLConnection connection = null;

                try
                {
                    url = new URL(address);

                    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.setConnectTimeout(10 * 1000);
                    connection.setReadTimeout(10 * 1000);

                    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    connection.connect();

                    int response = connection.getResponseCode();

                    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    // Here we create a new Message to send to the Handler object on the Activity
                    //  Send the response code, ping time, and the address
                    Message msg = Message.obtain(handler);
                    msg.arg1 = response;
                    msg.arg2 = (int) (end - start);
                    msg.obj = address;
                    msg.sendToTarget();
                }
                catch(MalformedURLException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch(IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: That all looks to be exactly what I want I have checked through it several times but I still get the "App has stopped working" message when a list item is clicked :/ any ideas?

Comment: Post the Stack Trace, or the last 5 lines up to the Exception

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your stack-trace, I think you may be getting a `NetworkOnMaintThreadException` because you're doing the HTTP connection on the Main/UI thread. Do it in a separate thread, perhaps by using an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), then you should be fine.

Comment: So I have to make a new AsyncTask class to ping the url?

Comment: @gravysam Yes you do, you can check this previous answer I did on the same topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572285/gson-and-google/16572315#16572315

Answer (score 0):

Which Android-Version are you using? The App may crash because you are doing a network call on the UI-Main-Thread, which means that the UI freezes during the network call. In older versions it works without getting an exception. Since Version 2.3.x(correct me if I'm wrong) you get the `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Take a look in this post for more information how to solve this problem:
- [How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: I'm using 4.2.2, so I have to make a new AsyncTask class to ping the url?

Comment: Yes you need to. Normally you should see the exception in your stacktrace as soren.qvist mentioned in his post.